# Cypress and Gitlab CI/CD integration

Tags: docker, npm, gitlab, cypress

Hey I'd like to run my cypress tests using gitlab pipelines. I've got the following docker image

```
FROM cypress/browsers:latest

ARG DIR="/usr/tests/e2e"
ENV NODE_MODULES_PATH="$DIR/node_modules"
WORKDIR $DIR
COPY ./tests/e2e/package*.json ./
RUN npm ci
```

which is built at the beginning of the pipeline as a first job. My `.gitlab-ci.yml` file looks as follows

```
image-e2e:
  build and push a docker image
  ...

test-e2e-staging:
  stage: test-staging
  image: registry.gitlab.com/.../e2e:latest
  script:
    - cd tests/e2e
    - npm run e2e:ci
  environment:
    name: staging
  needs: ["deploy-frontend-staging", "deploy-backend-staging"]
  dependencies: []
  allow_failure: false
```

The `e2e:ci` command simply runs cypress

```
"e2e:ci": "cypress run --headless --browser chrome --config-file cypress/config/cypress.json",
```

But the job output on gitlab gives me a following error

```
> cypress run --headless --browser chrome --config-file cypress/config/cypress.json
sh: 1: cypress: not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! e2e@1.0.0 e2e:ci: `cypress run --headless --browser chrome --config-file cypress/config/cypress.json`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the e2e@1.0.0 e2e:ci script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-05-01T12_59_51_436Z-debug.log
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks a lot in advance. Also I got a cypress dependency in the `devDependencies` section in `package.json`. The `image-e2e` job gives me the following output

```
Step 6/6 : RUN npm ci
 ---> Running in ed278e712827
> cypress@9.5.4 postinstall /usr/tests/e2e/node_modules/cypress
> node index.js --exec install
```

so it looks like cypress has been successfully installed here

Answer (score 1):

As it complains about `cypress not found`, why don't you simply switch to `cypress/included` docker image, no need to install cypress on the fly.